# Flutter model json

Tags: flutter, api, dart, model

How do I retrieve the information in the address? Attempted to retrieve information I can fetch but the Items class part is not fetching the address part. I'm practicing the fetch api.

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct. or may be stuck with some part of the problem i try to fix please help me

```
 List<Items> _list = [];
 List<Items> _search = [];
 var loading = false;
 Future fetchMos() async {
setState(() {
  loading = true;
});
_list.clear();
var client = http.Client();
String mosUrl =
    '';
var url = Uri.parse(mosUrl);
var headers = {'Client-Token': ''};
var response = await client.get(url, headers: headers);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = jsonDecode((utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)))['items'];
  setState(() {
    for (Map i in data) {
      _list.add(Items.fromJson(i));
      loading = false;
    }
  });
}
}
```

This is class model

```
            class Items {
                  String? custnum;
                   String? name;
                 List<Address>? address;
                   Items({this.custnum, this.name, this.address});

         Items.fromJson(json) {
        custnum = json['custnum'];
                 name = json['name'];
           if (json['address'] != null) {
           address = <Address>[];
              json['address'].forEach((v) {
              address!.add(new Address.fromJson(v));
                  });
            }
         }

          Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
              final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
           data['custnum'] = this.custnum;
            data['name'] = this.name;
             if (this.address != null) {
                 data['address'] = this.address!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
           }
                    return data;
          }
    }
         
           class Address {
              int? shipto;
           String? addr1;
                 String? thanon;
           String? tambon;
          String? amphur;
           String? provCode;
           String? province;
                    String? country;
               String? phone;
           String? email;
          String? postcode;
              String? contact;
           String? latitude;
         String? longitude;
           String? fax;
              String? soi;

              Address(
                {this.shipto,
         this.addr1,
           this.thanon,
          this.tambon,
           this.amphur,
           this.provCode,
             this.province,
           this.zipcode,
             this.country,
           this.phone,
             this.email,
           this.postcode,
           this.contact,
                  this.latitude,
             this.longitude,
         this.fax,
               this.soi});
    
          Address.fromJson(json) {
             shipto = json['shipto'];
          addr1 = json['addr1'];
            thanon = json['thanon'];
         tambon = json['tambon'];
         amphur = json['amphur'];
         provCode = json['prov_code'];
             province = json['province'];
           zipcode = json['zipcode'];
               country = json['country'];
                     phone = json['phone'];
        email = json['email'];
       postcode = json['postcode'];
          contact = json['contact'];
                          latitude = json['latitude'];
        longitude = json['longitude'];
               fax = json['fax'];
       soi = json['soi'];
         }

                 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
         data['shipto'] = this.shipto;
          data['addr1'] = this.addr1;
         data['thanon'] = this.thanon;
         data['tambon'] = this.tambon;
           data['amphur'] = this.amphur;
         data['prov_code'] = this.provCode;
           data['province'] = this.province;
               data['zipcode'] = this.zipcode;
             data['phone'] = this.phone;
                     data['email'] = this.email;
                       data['postcode'] = this.postcode;
         data['contact'] = this.contact;
                data['longitude'] = this.longitude;
              data['fax'] = this.fax;
          data['soi'] = this.soi;
          return data;
         }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

var data =json.decode(response.body);

```
for (var i in data['items']) {
  _list.add(Items.fromJson(i));
  loading = false;
}
```

setState(() { });

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).